# Auto completing hostnames for script parameters

Tags: linux, bash

I have a script that takes a several parameters including hostnames:

`./MyScript.sh -p param1 -q param2 hostname1 hostname2 hostname3 ...`

Since the shell can tab complete hostnames for commands like `ssh`, I wonder if I can set up the same kind of thing for my script.  I'm aware of the `BASH_COMPLETION` environment variable and the script it points to.  But I don't know if these are the things I need to modify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the manual page about [*Programmable Completion Builtins*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html). You can pass `-A hostname` to `compgen` or `complete` to get a completion of host names. While this just gives you *locally known* host names it is the same what `ssh` is doing so it should be what you want.

Example:

```
$ complete -A hostname foo
$ foo <tab><tab>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a tutorial available [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/tabexpansion.html) and another good resource is the bash completion project which has completions for many standard utilities [here](https://bash-completion.alioth.debian.org/).

If you have a short list of hosts you want to complete then this might be enough for you:

```
complete -W "lisa homer bart marge maggie" MyScript.sh
```